# How to delete shared_ptr content and replace it with new object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wonder if there is a way to delete an object held by shared_ptr and create new one so all other copies of this shared_ptr would be still valid and point to this object?

Comment: No. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: You can dereference and copy to load new content.

Comment: But still other references will remain.

Comment: You'll need to call destructor on the current object, and then do a [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) to create another one.

Comment: Nothing stops you from assigning a new value to the existing object. Why do you need a new one?  See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I want to delete existing object and create new one with different input data (same type). And I want the rest of pointers to be still valid (point to new object).

Comment: @BartekBoczar Is this a single-threaded application or a multi-threaded one where synchronization is an issue? And will the new object use the very same destructor or might it use a different one (due to polymorphic types)?

Comment: Why don't you make it a shared pointer to a unique pointer?

Comment: This is what assignment was invented for:  `*p = new_value;`

Answer (score 7):

You simply [reassign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) or [reset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) it.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> func(std::shared_ptr<T> m)
{
    m = std::make_shared<T>(T{});
    //m.reset();
    //m.reset(new int(56));
    return m;
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp1 = std::make_shared<int>(44);
    auto sp2 = func(sp1);
    //sp1 is still valid after its copy was altered in func
    std::cout << *sp1 << '\n' << *sp2 << std::endl;
}
```